# python: Send string value without using string

Tags: java, python, django, string, numberformatexception

I'm setting a python application that uses an external module padelpy that wraps the access to a rest API: `from padelpy import padeldescriptor`

I have a dictionary with settings names and values:

```
settings = {
    'fingerprints': False,
    'd2_d': False,
    ...
}
```

I loop through the received POST.request parameters to check which setting(s) to communicate as true:

```
for setting in settings.keys():
    if setting in request.POST:
        settings.update({setting: request.POST.get(setting)})
        str_conf = '%s=TRUE' % setting
        padeldescriptor(str_conf)
```

if I use

```
padeldescriptor(fingerprints=TRUE)
```

it works

but if I use

```
padeldescriptor(str_conf)
```

it's the same as sending `padeldescriptor("fingerprints=TRUE")`

and I get an error back from the server:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "fingerprints=TRUE"
```

How can I send the settings without using strings?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Dictionary unpacking to do this

`padeldescriptor(**settings)` should work. What that does is unpack everything in your dictionary as keyword arguments to that function.

Comment: I want to send `padeldescriptor(fingerprints=True)`

I could use an implementation of a switch case but there are other settings that need to pass values instead of True, e.g.: `padeldescriptor(threads=2)`

Comment: Exactly. The problem is that your are sending a string, not a series of arguments to `padeldescriptor`. Rather than doing the string formatting, what you can do is unpack your `settings` dictionary that you have (with each setting set as you are doing in `settings.update` to pass all your arguments to `padeldescriptor`